# Open Layers 4.0.1 Pausing Marker Animation?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, animation, animatedmarker

I am using open layers 4. I am moving and stoping marker animation as [this](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-move-animation.html) example without any problem. But I want to add pause and continue functionality to marker also. I edit some variables and endeavor on the issue with these functions. But `elapsedTime` is negative on `moveFeature` function continuously.

```
 function pauseAnimation() {
            animating = false;
            //I hold elapsed time globally
            var index = Math.round($("[id='rightfrm:tbv1:txt1']").val() * elapsedTime / 1000);
            (geoMarker.getGeometry()).setCoordinates(line_coordinates[index].lc);
            map.un('postcompose', moveFeature);
        }

 function continueAnimation() {
    animating = true;
    now = new Date().getTime();
    now = now - 10000 + elapsedTime; // --10000-- for negativeness
    geoMarker.setStyle(null);
    map.on('postcompose', moveFeature);
    map.render();
 }
```

How should I add pause and continue functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem. It was a logical error. Pause and Continue working now

```
now = new Date().getTime() - elapsedTime;
```

Anyone can use these functions for Pause/Continue functionality.

Comment: I'm also using same functionality.. 
 Based on Animation speed, feature point should travel speed or fast..

`replayIndex = Math.round(speed * elapsedTime / 1000);`